# JupyterHub - oauth_client_id not found

Tags: oauth, jupyterhub

I am using Azure to run python notebook using Jupyterhub. After spinning up the VM, I was able to access the notebooks just by using my username and password (just like ssh). However, one day later when I switched to another network (I am not claiming that the network might have been a problem) I am unable to access the link. It gives me `The site can't be reached` error.

So I tried rerunning the process again, and since then I have been struggling to make it run again. I have searched for similar issues on GitHub, but they aren't helpful either.

After the kill the process using `kill pid` command, I tried running the jupyterhub through this command:

```
/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser --port=50387 --notebook-dir="~/notebooks" --config=/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py
```

And it gives me the error:

```
 JUPYTERHUB_API_TOKEN env is required to run jupyterhub-singleuser. Did you launch it manually?
```

So I searched through github issues similar to this. I tried generating token manually using:

```
 jupyterhub token username
```

And I added that token to JUPYTERHUB_API_TOKEN via `export JUPYTERHUB_API_TOKEN=token`. I also added token:username to c.Authenticator.tokens in jupyterhub_config.py. Now I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 528, in get
    value = obj._trait_values[self.name]
KeyError: 'oauth_client_id'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/bin/jupyterhub-singleuser", line 6, in <module>
    main()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 455, in main
    return SingleUserNotebookApp.launch_instance(argv)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyter_core/application.py", line 267, in launch_instance
    return super(JupyterApp, cls).launch_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 657, in launch_instance
    app.initialize(argv)
  File "<decorator-gen-7>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 87, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 1296, in initialize
    self.init_webapp()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 393, in init_webapp
    self.init_hub_auth()
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/singleuser.py", line 388, in init_hub_auth
    if not self.hub_auth.oauth_client_id:
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 556, in __get__
    return self.get(obj, cls)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 535, in get
    value = self._validate(obj, dynamic_default())
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 593, in _validate
    value = self._cross_validate(obj, value)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 599, in _cross_validate
    value = obj._trait_validators[self.name](obj, proposal)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 907, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/anaconda/envs/py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterhub/services/auth.py", line 439, in _ensure_not_empty
    raise ValueError("%s cannot be empty." % proposal.trait.name)
ValueError: oauth_client_id cannot be empty.
```

I am not sure where I went wrong in this process. Anybody familiar with this issue?

Comment: Did you solve this? How?

Comment: Hey! My problem was that the outgoing traffic to the port 8000 was being blocked by the network admin. Once that was solved, I was able to access jupyter and this problem never came up again. Sorry can't be of much help here!

Answer (score 1):

Try running `jupyterhub` instead of `jupyterhub-singleuser` 
For your specific use case, the command would be as follows:
`sudo /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/python /anaconda/envs/py35/bin/jupyterhub --port=50387 --notebook-dir="~/notebooks" --config=/etc/jupyterhub/jupyterhub_config.py`

Make sure that jupyterhub is installed (correctly) in the path you mentioned.

Comment: I did that, but its still not running jupyterhub-singleuser; --notebook-dir is not recognized

Comment: Don't run jupyterhub-singleuser directly. Run jupyterhub it will internally execute jupyterhub-singleuser. Please edit the question if you get any new errors. (or new logs)